# Why does Rust ask for type annotations for .collect()?

Tags: rust

Given the below code which is explicit enough I think why does Rust ask for type annotations?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6be49d596d8d0ae77a9edea3ff32c71a)

```rust
pub struct Score {
    pub id: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let rows = vec![
        Score{
            id: None,
        },
        Score{
            id: Some("test".to_string()),
        },
    ];
    
    let existing_scores = rows
        .iter()
        .map(|o| o.id.unwrap_or_default())
        .collect();
        
    dbg!(existing_scores);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust asks for type annotations because, currently, there is no way to know what is the type of `existing_scores`. This is because `collect` is an interface that allows producing several kind of data structures. You could specify which type you want to collect to with *the turbofish* `.collect::<T>()`.

For instance, `existing_scores` could be a [`HashSet<_>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75079850a1f9e0bf2522b59f7cc1c454) or to a [`Vec<_>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=012473f926ad73d58e24d3098162df8f) (note that I had to modify your example to make it work, by turning `iter()` into `into_iter()`, otherwise it won't work).

Note that, in practice, if you use `existing_scores` somewhere else that determines its type, Rust will not necessarily ask you to explicitly give a type hint.